# Revert reversion in git with branch, and readably

Tags: git, version-control

This question is about how to revert a revert in git, and to do it in a way that makes sense to future readers and never puts the repository in a bad state.

My git repository had for a while HEAD (on master) pointing to a very Good commit:

```
HEAD
   |
   G
```

And then some development happened, on branches, and those commits looked good, so they got merged into master.

```
               HEAD
                  |
G -- C1 -- ... -- Ck
```

But then we found a subtle bug somewhere in those commits.  It was clear that we could just roll back to G and then take some time to think this through.  So we did that.  Commit R is a revert that came about by typing something like

```
$ git checkout -b B
$ git checkout master
$ git revert --no-commit G..HEAD
```

That put my repository in a state like this, where being at R and being at G look the same except for history:

```
                     HEAD
                        |
G -- C1 -- ... -- Ck -- R
                  |
                  B
```

Then some more development happened: some emergency commits on master (E1, E2) and some additional development on B (D1, ..., Dj) that corrected the problems we had at Ck and continued some other important work.  Now the repository looks like this:

```
                                HEAD
                                   |
G -- C1 -- ... -- Ck -- R -- E1 -- E2
                  |
                   \ -- D1 -- ... -- Dj
                                     |
                                     B
```

Good, it's only been a day, but it's time to put things back in order.  What I want is a repository that looks something like this:

```
                                                           HEAD
                                                              |
G -- C1 -- ... -- Ck -- R -- E1 -- E2 -- (-R) -- D1 -- ... -- Dj
```

where (-R) is a commit that undoes R.  And I'd like to do this in some reasonable way so that it's clear to future readers what has happened.

The best way I've thought of to do this is this:

```
$ git checkout B
$ git rebase master
$ git revert R
# Use the rebase -i to change ordering so that R happens before D1:
$ git rebase -i master
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --ff-only B
$ git push
```

I'm reasonably sure that will work, but I feel like I'm missing something.  Any suggestions to help me improve my git-fu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, another 2 ways with few steps.

**1:**

```
git checkout B
git rebase -i master
git branch -D master
git branch -m B master
```

**2:**

```
git rebase --onto Ck R E2
git rebase --onto <current SHA-1> Ck Dj
git checkout -b temp
git branch -D master
git branch -m temp master
```

So the master branch will look like:

```
G -- C1 -- ... -- Ck -- E1 -- E2 -- D1 -- ... -- Dj     master
```

Comment: In the end, I used rebase (or maybe it was cherry-pick) to pull over the missing commits, then (the key idea I didn't know about) I used `git branch -m` to move master to master-old, then B to master, then push both.  I'll delete master-old soon.  (Yes, the reflog also provides a recovery path, but this is easier to remember.)

Answer (score 1):

I am also pretty sure it will work. Here other's way -

Cherry-pick `E1 & E2` before `D1` using `rebase -i`.

```
                                   HEAD
                                   |
G -- C1 -- ... -- Ck -- R -- E1 -- E2
                  |
                   \ -- E1 -- E2 -- D1 -- ... -- Dj
                                                 |
                                                 B
```

Then replace `master` branch with `B` branch.

```
$ git checkout B
$ git branch -D master                   # delete master
$ git checkout -b master                 # create master from B
$ git push -f origin master              # force(-f) push and replace remote master's history by local master
```